# what does AVMediaTypeMuxed mean?

Tags: ios

Simple question: what does `AVMediaTypeMuxed` mean?

I'm looking at some sample code (below) and it doesn't return anything on my iPad 2. So is `AVMediaTypeMuxed` a device media type that only exists on the iPhone?

```
AVCaptureDevice *muxedDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeMuxed];
if (muxedDevice) {
    NSLog (@"got muxedDevice");
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *muxedInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:muxedDevice
                                                                             error:&setUpError];
    if (muxedInput) {
        [captureSession addInput:muxedInput];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

mux is a shortened version of multiplex; muxed media is therefore media where multiple streams have been combined together into a single stream — usually that means audio and video streams are combined into a single byte stream.

I would therefore be unsurprised if there's no default multiplexed media output device, as Apple may simply have decided that the default inputs are the cameras and the microphone separately.

Comment: Since I only have an iPad to test on I was thinking it was some iPhone thing. The docs say it is available in iOS 4.0 and later so it is not some older format. Apple source code seems to preference `AVMediaTypeVideo` + `AVMediaTypeAudio` together, with the fallback to `AVMediaTypeMuxed` - confusing.

Comment: Muxed devices include things like DV camcorders on the Mac where, like Tommy says, the audio and video are interleaved in one stream, so they have both audio and video characteristics.

While there may not be a default muxed device, it's possible the user could connect such a device via the dock/lightning connector.

Comment: Does anyone have a **definitive** answer to whether AVMediaTypeMuxed **exclusively** means the stream contains video and audio? Or can a muxed device contain any other combination of media types?